dompdf, the resulting pdf displays a blank page on the first page
I used dompdf to create digital certificates for participants. The PDF was successfully created, but there was a problem, the resulting PDF displayed a blank page on the first page, which should not be there.
if I echo the html code, there are no errors and it displays as I want
Here is the code I created:
            ....

            $html='
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            </head>
            <style>
                @page{margin:0px;}
                @font-face {
                  font-family: "Tangerine_Regular";
                  font-style: normal;
                  font-weight: 500;
                  src: url("https://qrcode.ffpm-iafmi.com/sertifikat/Tangerine_Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
                }
                body{margin:0px;}
                #bgs{
                    width:841pt;
                    height:595pt;
                    background:url(bg1.png);
                    background-size:contain;
                    background-repeat:no-repeat;
                    padding-top:345px;
                    text-align:center;
                    font-family:arial;
                    line-height:1;
                    overflow:hidden;
                    left: 0px; 
                    top: 0px;
                    right: 0px;
                    bottom: 0px;
                }
                #spk{
                    width:841pt;
                    height:595pt;
                    background:url(bg2.jpg);
                    background-size:contain;
                    background-repeat:no-repeat;
                }
                .names{
                  font-family: "Tangerine_Regular", serif;
                  font-size:70px;
                  font-weight:500;
                  color:#192489;
                }
            </style>
            <body>
                <div id="bgs">
                    <span class="names"><u>'.$name.'</u></span><br/>
                    <span style="font-size:22px;"><i>'.$roles.'</i></span>
                </div>
                <div id="spk"></div>
            </body>
            </html>';
            
        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
        $dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled',true);
        $dompdf->set_paper(array(0,0,841,595));
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream("e-Certificate for ".$name);
        //echo $html;
    }

what am I missing in my script?

Instead of width:841pt; height:595pt; you could try position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;right: 0px; bottom: 0px;, see: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/892 Sorry, I'm too lazy to try it myself, but I think it's a good idea to not rely on absolute dimensions.

DompDF  "Handles most CSS 2.1 and a few CSS3 properties, including ,import, media & page rules". So, import BootstrapCSS like this it's not working.

@KIKOSoftware , i have tried it before to use style like that, but it gave me 3 pages, The second page is the same as the first page (div with bg1.jpg as background), but without content in it,
the third page appears as expected

I have managed to find the solution for my problem, it seems the problem is in the writing of the style (padding-top: 345px).
so, I removed the style and i placed a div inside the first div with a style height: 345px. and the first blank page is gone.
here are the settings I use
1.remove padding-top style:
#bgs{
    width:841pt;
    height:595pt;
    background:url(bg1.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
    line-height:1;
}

2.then placed a div inside the first div with a style height:345px
<div id="bgs">
    <div style="width:1000px;height:345px;"></div>
    <span class="namanya"><u>'.$name.'</u></span><br/>
    <span style="font-size:22px;"><i>'.$roles.'</i></span>
</div>
<div id="spk"></div>

So, in my opinion, there is an issue with the use of margin and padding
